# Django view definition with subfolder not rendering correctly in second time

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app **accounts** and in my Login link, when I click for the first time, it loads correctly:
[image]

When I click for the second time it loads incorrectly. It basically trying to add the account/login at the end of the previous URL. I want to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login when I click on the Login link, no matter I many times I have clicked on it.
[image]

I am a newbie on Django and Python. I have tried to redirect, render, if-else statement and still no luck.

Here are the details, I have an app name **accounts** in my project. The project urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [path("accounts/", include("accounts.urls"))
].
```

The account app urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("login", views.login, name="login"),
].
```

The accounts app has two view function register and login:

```
def register(request):
   return render(request, "register.html")
def login(request):
    return render(request, "login.html")
```

I am using two links,

```
<li><a href="accounts/login">Login</a><i></i></li>
    <li><a href="accounts/register">Register</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using, `accounts/login` but not `/accounts/login` in href `<a href="accounts/login">Login</a>`
However it would be even better if you used [url template tag from django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

Add name to url patterns

```
urlpatterns = [path("accounts/", include("accounts.urls"), name="accounts")].
```

Then use it in html like so

```html
<li><a href="{% url 'accounts' %}">Login</a><i></i></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced up such case. The probelm is the following code.

```
<li><a href="accounts/login">Login</a><i></i></li>
<li><a href="accounts/register">Register</a></li>
```

Replace that the following one.

```
<li><a href="/accounts/login">Login</a><i></i></li>
<li><a href="/accounts/register">Register</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

- in your project `urls.py`, add a `namespace`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls'), namespace='accounts')
].
```

- in The `account` app `urls.py`, add a trailing `/`

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
].
```

- in your html, use the buitin url template tag `{% url 'APPNAME:VIEWNAME' %}`

```
<li><a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Login</a><i></i></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'accounts:register' %}">Register</a></li>
```